# Ansible: running multiple commands and/or services best practices

Tags: ansible

I have a few best practice questions. I am currently running multiple commands in a task like so:

```yaml
- name: Update NTP
  become: TRUE
  command: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - service ntp stop
    - ntpd -gq
    - service ntp start
```

When I run it, it works fine and I get a warning saying I should use the Service module. Fair enough. I create the following:

```yaml
- name: NTP Stop
  become: TRUE
  service:
    name: ntp
    state: stopped

- name: Update NTP
  become: TRUE
  command: "ntpd -gq"

- name: NTP Start
  become: TRUE
  service:
    name: ntp
    state: started
```

This also works fine. My question is: is one way better than the other? I can see that readability and "documentation" might improve by dissecting each command into its own Task, but at the cost of creating much more code.

Is there a benefit to creating separate tasks for every command and/or service that could potentially just be grouped together into one tidy task? Either from a technical or QA point of view?

Comment: Regarding "_Is one way better than the other?_" and "_Is there a benefit to creating separate tasks?_" it will depend on your environment, the goal you try to achieve, how it should be executed and maintained later, etc. It will lead more to opinion based than fact based answers. The best practice is probably to keep things as easiest, smallest and simplest as possible, to maintain least complexity.

Comment: One of the best practice is to make sure your tasks are idempotent, i.e. produce the exact same result on every run and report if anything was changed to align the target to the described state. Your first example does not conform to that rule as every each element in the loop will report "changed" and that it might become hard to implement a "changed_when" directive that will apply to any of the looped command.  `systemd` module is idempotent by default so your second example would only need to possibly fix one task. But I'm almost sure simply restarting the service would be sufficient.

Comment: @Zeitounator That is a very good point, and the type of answer I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your question that you are interested in general "*How to update and restart a service process?*".

Depending on your environment this can be done in example via [`systemd`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/systemd_module.html) module.

```yaml
- name: Update and restart 'ntpd' service
  systemd:
    name: ntpd
    daemon_reload: true
    enabled: true
    state: restarted
```

The [`service`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_module.html) module

> ... acts as a proxy to the underlying service manager module.

Comment: This was more of a general "best practices" question rather than a technical question as to whether it was better to have multiple tasks compared to one big task with multiple commands. 

That said, your answer is definitely far neater than my solution, so I thank you for that!